# how to link YCM through ruby shims that rbenv provide

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

We often run with multiple ruby versions and often I have to recompile YCM when I switch as sometimes I get errors like segfaults or can't find ruby.

I was wondering, how do I get YCM to compile by linking to ruby via the shim so that no matter which version of ruby is running it should (theoretically) link to the current one?

Or is there a better (read correct) way to deal with this for YCM?

Comment: Why don't you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mMontu, I found a solution in an issue tracker, the answer isn't to get ycm to compile with the current ruby but rather to ensure the correct version that YCM is compiled with is set before opening Vim, you can do that by following the steps found [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/151#issuecomment-74452227).

The specific steps are:

1. If you use Homebrew to install vim, you should update Homebrew: `brew update` or update with your package manager specific upgrade update command.
2. If you already installed vim use Homebrew, remove it: `brew remove vim`
3. Use the system Ruby to compile and install vim:

   - for rvm do `rvm <system|ruby version> do brew install vim`
   - for rbenv install the [only](https://github.com/Rodreegez/rbenv-only) plugin and then do `rbenv only -r <ruby version> -c ""brew install vim`
4. Make a function to acces vim:

   - for rvm do:

   `function vim()
   {
     cmd="exec /usr/local/bin/vim $@"
     rvm $GLOBAL_RUB_VERSION do "$cmd";
   }`

   - for rbenv do:

   `function vim()
   {
     cmd="exec /usr/local/bin/vim $@"
     rbenv only -r $GLOBAL_RUB_VERSION -c "$cmd";
   }`